# Attempting to create a Facebook post on a Facebook page with multiple images and videos using the Meta API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I am implementing a class that handles creating Facebook posts using requests to the Meta API. The process is divided into two phases for images and videos, respectively. Following the documentation, an independent upload must be done for each image or video. Subsequently, with the IDs returned in the response to each request, the data is generated using attached_media and a list of {"media_fbid":"image_id|video_id"}. The flow of the task works correctly without any issues when it comes to images. However, the problem arises when a video is in the attached_media list. Does anyone know what could be the solution to the following error?

```
{'error': {'message': '(#10) Application does not have permission for this action', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 10, 'fbtrace_id': 'ApRVBhzB6YA2XsOYRSa6DJE'}}
```

class here:

```
class FacebookHelper:
    def __init__(self, publication: Publication, business: Business = None):
        self.publication = publication
        if not business:
            self.business = self.publication.business
        else:
            self.business = business
        self.update_business_access_token()
        self.write_timeout = get_configuration_by_key("write_timeout")

    def update_business_access_token(self):
        if (
            not self.business.page_access_token
            or not self.business.session_access_token_date
            or now() - self.business.session_access_token_date > timedelta(hours=2)
        ):
            with httpx.Client(
                base_url=get_configuration_by_key("meta_api_url")
            ) as client:
                params = {
                    "fields": "access_token",
                    "access_token": self.business.related_meta_app.access_token,
                }
                try:
                    response = client.get(url=self.business.page_id, params=params)
                    data = response.json()
                    self.business.page_access_token = data["access_token"]
                    self.business.session_access_token_date = now()
                    self.business.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    raise

    def post_publication(self):
        with httpx.Client(base_url=get_configuration_by_key("meta_api_url")) as client:
            params = {
                "access_token": self.business.page_access_token,
                "published": True,
            }
            try:
                response = client.post(
                    url=f"{self.business.page_id}/feed",
                    params=params,
                    data=self.generate_data(),
                )
                data = response.json()
                print(data)
                self.publication.post_id = data["id"]
                self.publication.published = True
                self.publication.publish_hour = None
                self.publication.publish_date = None
                self.publication.ready_to_publish = False
                self.publication.published_date = now()
                self.publication.last_publish_attempt_date = None
                self.publication.last_publish_attempt_error = None
            except Exception as e:
                self.publication.last_publish_attempt_date = now()
                self.publication.last_publish_attempt_error = f"{type(e)}"
                self.publication.last_publish_attempt_error_description = str(e)
            finally:
                self.publication.publishing = False
                self.publication.save()

    def post_image(self, image: Image):
        with httpx.Client(base_url=get_configuration_by_key("meta_api_url")) as client:
            files = {
                "file": image.image.file.read(),
            }
            data = {
                "access_token": self.business.page_access_token,
                "published": False,
            }
            try:
                response = client.post(
                    url=f"{self.business.page_id}/photos", files=files, data=data
                )
                data = response.json()
                print(data)
                image.post_id = data["id"]
                image.published = True
                image.published_date = now()
                image.last_publish_attempt_date = None
                image.last_publish_attempt_error = None
            except Exception as e:
                image.last_publish_attempt_date = now()
                image.last_publish_attempt_error = f"{type(e)}"
                image.last_publish_attempt_error_description = str(e)
            finally:
                image.save()

    def post_video(self, video: Video):
        timeout = httpx.Timeout(60, write=float(self.write_timeout))
        with httpx.Client(
            base_url=get_configuration_by_key("meta_video_api_url")
        ) as client:
            files = {
                "source": video.video.file.open('rb'),
            }
            data = {
                "access_token": self.business.page_access_token,
                "published": False,
            }
            try:
                response = client.post(
                    url=f"{self.business.page_id}/videos",
                    files=files,
                    data=data,
                    timeout=timeout,
                )
                data = response.json()
                print(data)
                video.post_id = data["id"]
                video.published = True
                video.published_date = now()
            except Exception as e:
                video.last_publish_attempt_date = now()
                video.last_publish_attempt_error = f"{type(e)}"
                video.last_publish_attempt_error_description = str(e)
            finally:
                video.save()

    def generate_data(self):
        data = {}
        media = []
        if self.publication.text:
            data["message"] = self.publication.text
        for image in self.publication.image_set.filter(published=True):
            media.append({"media_fbid": image.post_id})
        for video in self.publication.video_set.filter(published=True):
            media.append({"media_fbid": video.post_id})
        data["attached_media"] = json.dumps(media)
        print(data)
        return data

    def multiple_post(self):
        for image in self.publication.image_set.filter(published=False):
            self.post_image(image)
        for video in self.publication.video_set.filter(published=False):
            self.post_video(video)
        self.post_publication()
```